# How to beautify a small gap between porch and sidewalk

Tags: porch

I have a very small gap between my cement porch and the sidewalk. I'm looking for a creative way to dress it up a bit.  Are there thin, oblong stones that could be layered in a small space?  The space is 4.5" tall on both sides, and 4' in the middle. Looking for ideas.
[image: Porch]

Comment: can you zoom out a bit? It's best to match your other surroundings.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Is that 4.5" tall at the sides and 4" tall in the middle, or 4' long? Also, it's likely that this will be closed as a "arts/crafts/decoration" question which is explicitly off-topic. If you'll take the [tour] and read through the [help] (especially the "what can I ask about" section) you'll see what's on topic and off. Maybe you can find a less "decorator-y" way of asking (like "how should I fill this to prevent water ingress") to keep it open.